# Is it possible to package a java project with unzipping external jars and updating them together?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a Config project which aims to basically pull some artifacts of other projects and unzips it and add few classes to it, add some jars and edit a couple of files and then package it and publish it on artifactory.
Currently this is being done with ant, can it be done with maven entirely, so that it can be put in a Gitlab ci pipeline. If yes, is there an existing documentation or help associated with it?
I am new to java building and packaging.

Comment: First can you explain why you are repacking things like and editing and repacking things? To be honest it sounds weird... technically you can do things like this (using maven-assembly-plugin + maybe plus some other plugins). It would be helpful to have a full description what you need to do?

Comment: I can blame it on state of project delivery, it's pretty old, and packaging vary on the customer level, different flavours for different customers.